# Python & Multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

```
import multiprocessing

def main(a):
    while True:
        print(a)

p = multiprocessing.process(target=main(1))
p0 = multiprocessing.process(target=main(2))
p.start()
p0.start()
```

If you run the code it just prints:

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

It actullay should output something like this

```
1
2
1
1
2
2
2
1
2
1
2
```

How do I fix this: I'm doing research since this morning. Please send help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this meet your requirements?

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def fun(a):
    while True:
        print(a)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=fun, args=(1,)) # that's how you should pass arguments
    p.start()
    p1 = Process(target=fun, args=(2,))  
    p1.start()
```

output:

```
1
2
1
2
2
2
2
2
2
1
```

Comment: How should I do it, if I have no arguments to pass?

Comment: what do you mean no arguments? your function expects one `fun(a):` the (a) means it is expecting some variable. If you don't want it to be able to accept any variables change it to `fun()`